# \setlength from .cls file ignored

Tags: spacing, document-classes

I am creating a custom .cls file for my dissertation. The full file is too much for a minimal working example, and perhaps unnecessary to answer my question. That said, I'm open to editing the question to add more information as needed.

Tweaking the table of contents, I am trying to adjust the horizontal space between "Chapter n" and "Title of chapter n"

[image]

As pointed out in the comments, `em` scales with the font size, but not with the horizontal space I am trying to adjust. Here is the space set to 0.7`em` when font size is set to 10pt:
[image]

However, this static 0.7`em` does not look as nice when the font size is 11pt:
[image]
This can be done in the portion of the .cls file defining chapters:

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                     \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                     \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                               {\@chapapp~\thechapter\hspace{<length goes here>}{#1}}
```

I can manually set it to different values but what I'd like to do is define a new length, `\chapsep`, that varies depending on the font size. I have tried variations of the following code to no effect:

```
\newlength{\chapsep}
\if@compatibility
  \renewcommand\@ptsize{0}
\else
  \DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}\setlength\chapsep{0.7em}}
\fi
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}\setlength\chapsep{1.2em}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}\setlength\chapsep{0.1em}}
```

No matter what I do nothing seems to change the length, and when I print it (using the `printlen` package) I can see it stays at 0.0pt. If I set the length outside of the option declaration or conditional statements related to the font size, the command works as expected.

I'd welcome explanations for why `\setlength` is ignored (maybe I'm not using the right syntax for `DeclareOption`?) as well as suggestions on how to adjust this new length. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Silly question: did you remember to `\ProcessOptions`?

Comment: @WillieWong The command is there, several lines after the `\DeclareOptions` commands.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. What I did: created a blank `.cls` that does only `\LoadClass{report}` and your code (with the still missing brace fixed inside the conditional, and adding `\ProcessOptions`). Then I created a document that only `\usepackage{printlen}` and prints the length of `\chapsep`. It works. (Except if you don't pass a font-size option: you may want to include a default value.) So whatever is not working is in the code you are not showing us.

Comment: As an aside: given that `em` units already scale with font size, I am a little surprised with what you are trying to do. What is the use case here of having different (non-proportional) spacing where you indicated?

Comment: @WillieWong Any idea where to start looking? Though em scales with font size, I was trying to line up the chapter titles with the section titles below. This distance does not scale nicely, and when I get it perfect in one font size it looks off in a different one. Will update the question with a visual for what I'd like.

Comment: Well, I would suggest start by taking a copy of your `cls` file, and a dummy `tex` file as I did, and then start deleting stuff in the `cls` file from the bottom until you find the problem.  (Basically the same process as how one would go about creating a MWE.)

Comment: @WillieWong I was really hoping it was just bad syntax. The search (and creation of a MWE) begins...

Comment: For your actual problem: I would suggest you not completely reinvent the wheel. The alignment of TOC entries in the standard classes are done via the `\contentsline` command, the first argument of which allows the computation of the indentation AND the width to reserve for the label. Is there any reason you wish to avoid modern packages like `titletoc` or `tocloft` and instead wishes to do things by hand? If you must do things by hand, I would suggest aligning things with judicious uses of `\hspace` to reserve space for the label and `\rlap` or `\llap` when printing `Chapter 1` and `1.1`.

Comment: With your current set-up, it is not at all clear to me that the lengths you tuned to match 'Chapter 1' with section '1.1' will work with '1.2' or later chapters.

Comment: `\setlength\chapsep{0.1em}` will store the em value of the currently active font. You could delay the setting to the document begin, when \normalsize has already been called with e.g. `\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\setlength....}`. Or use `\newcommand\chapsep{1em}` and then `\hspace{\chapsep}` will pick up the size of the chapter font.

Comment: @WillieWong I was using tocloft for other parts of the TOC, but because because of the `\hspace` command, `\cftchapaftersnumb` was effectively ignored. TL;DR: user error. It eventually dawned on me that if I used `\numberline{\thechapter}` I could let tocloft handle everything. The reason why the lengths need to be adjusted for different font sizes comes down to the fact that per university requirements each new level must be indented exactly 0.5in, which does not scale with font size to make entries more or less aligned.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Using a command instead of a length solved the problem. I was able to combine this with Willie Wong's suggestion (tocloft) to achieve a nice result.